# I can't delete realtime record in angular with firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have this code in angular, I want to delete a record and create it in real time, when I create a product it creates it well, but when I delete it it doesn't work, it only works if I update the browser. I don't know where the code may fail.

I thought it could be in getProducts (): Promise , because when I click Delete it creates a product and when I update the browser it deletes it.

I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

**My data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Producto } from '../interfaces/producto';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from "ngx-spinner";
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private colProduct: string = 'Products';
  private products: Producto[] = [];

  constructor(private _firestore: AngularFirestore, private _spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {

  }


  showSpinner(): void {
    this._spinner.show();
  }
  hideSpinner(): void {
    this._spinner.hide();
  }
  showAlert(icon: any, title: string, text: string, showConfirmButton: boolean, position: any, timer: number) {
    Swal.fire({
      icon: icon,
      title: title,
      text: text,
      showConfirmButton: showConfirmButton,
      position: position,
      timer: timer

    })
  }

  updateProduct(data: any, id: string) {

  }

  deleteProduct(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return this._firestore.collection(this.colProduct).doc(id).delete();
  }

  createProduct(producto: Producto): Promise<any> {
    return this._firestore.collection(this.colProduct).add(producto);
  }

  getProducts(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this._firestore.collection(this.colProduct).stateChanges().subscribe(collection => {
        collection.forEach((document) => {
          const data:any  = document.payload.doc.data();
          data.id = document.payload.doc.id;
          this.products.push(data);

        });


      resolve(this.products);


      });

    });
  }
}
```

**my components.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Producto } from '../shared/interfaces/producto';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataService } from '../shared/services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-catalogo',
  templateUrl: './catalogo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./catalogo.component.scss']
})
export class CatalogoComponent implements OnInit {

  public form: FormGroup;

  public productos: Producto[] = [];

  constructor(private _data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._data.getProducts().then((data: Producto[]) => {
      this.productos = data;
    });
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      pricing: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });

  }

  public saveForm(): void {
    this._data.showSpinner();
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const { title, description , pricing } = this.form.value;
      const newProduct: Producto = {
        title: title,
        description: description,
        pricing: pricing,
        image: "https://celadasa.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/156984-1000-1000/BQ7032-001.jpg",
        category: 'calzado',
        creationDate: new Date()

      }

      this._data.createProduct(newProduct).then(() => {
        this.form.reset();
        this._data.hideSpinner();
        this._data.showAlert('success', 'product', 'ok', false, 'center', 3500);

      });

    } else {
      this._data.hideSpinner();
      this._data.showAlert('error', 'form invalid', 'validad', false, 'center', 3500);
    }


  }


  delete(id) {
    this._data.showSpinner();
    this._data.deleteProduct(id).then(() => {
      this.form.reset();
      this._data.hideSpinner();
      this._data.showAlert('success', 'product delete', 'delete', false, 'center', 3500);

    });
  }
}
```

I don't know if the code goes in getProductos is or goes somewhere else or if I have to use pipe and map.

Comment: Check difference between `Promise vs Observable`

Comment: Your get production function need refactoring, i will update my answer

Comment: Check my answer update.

Comment: it works when i create a record but now it is not deleted it loads but it is not deleted

Comment: when i give to delete now it doesn't delete and it remains loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactoring your product listing function:

```
getProducts(): Observable<Producto[]> {
    this._firestore.collection<Producto>(this.colProduct).valueChanges();
}


this._data.getProducts().subscribe((data: Producto[]) => {
  this.productos = data;
});
```

**Update**

**Make Observable subscription inside component template.html**

**my components.ts**

```
  public productos: Producto[] = [];

  this._data.getProducts().subscribe((data: Producto[]) => {
      this.productos = data;
    });
>>
  public productos$: Observable<Producto[]>;

  this.productos$ = this._data.getProducts();
```

**my components.html**

```
  productos
>> 
  <div *ngFor="let product of productos$ | async"
   /** List each product item*/
  <div>
```

Comment: Please update your question with sample on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: ngzone did not work for me. I thought it could be in getProducts (): Promise <any>, because when I click Delete it creates a product and when I update the browser it deletes it.

Comment: Ok, Let me check.

Comment: Try to update delete function =>
deleteProduct(id: string): Promise<any> {     return 
this._firestore.doc< Producto>(`Products/${id}`).delete();
}

Comment: it gives me error in products / $ {id})

1 arguments expected, but 2.ts were obtained (2554)

Comment: sorry i'm new to this

Comment: No problem i will try to help you as far as i can :)

Comment: look, this code is the previous one, when I create or delete a product only the changes are saved if I update the browser

 / * this._firestore.collection (this.colProduct) .get (). subscribe (collection => {
          collection.forEach ((document) => {
            const data: any = document.data ();
            data.id = document.id;
            this.products.push (data);
   
          }); * /

Comment: I mean if you realize I was using get and changed it to statechanges () then add payload.doc.

Comment: Aha, Do you mean that when you delete product deleted on firebase and the list not updated on your UI, Is this you problem.

Comment: Your get products function is `Promise`, you need to convert it to Observable as your needs is stream for any updates, i will update my answer

Comment: How would I do that, because I'm doing an Angular and Firebase course, sorry

Comment: Updated my answer, please check and fix your types and feedback

Comment: t works when i create a record but now it is not deleted it loads but it is not deleted –

Comment: when i give to delete now it doesn't delete and it remains loading

Comment: Make Observable subscription  stream inside template => Check my answer update.